# Rebuild npm modules when deploying Meteor app

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

When deploying meteor app to my server, I first `meteor build` it, then untar the bundle on the server.

Next I do

```
cd server && npm install
```

But the npm packages included by meteorhacks:npm are not built? How can we rebuild them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried this from a clean checkout of a project that uses [npm](https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm):

1. Bundle your app to produce a `tar.gz` file in another directory.
2. When you extract your `tar.gz` file you should have a directory called `bundle`.
3. Your custom npm modules will be located in `bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-container/node_modules/`
4. To install fibers do: `cd bundle/programs/server/ && npm install`